# Convergence or Divergence of $\frac{(-1)^{n-1}\cdot n}{n^2 + 1}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

> Determine whether the sequence diverges or converges. If it's convergence, then find the limit:
>
> $$\frac{(-1)^{n-1}\cdot n}{n^2 + 1}$$

So the equation that I'm trying to solve is $[(-1)^{n-1}\cdot n]/[n^2 + 1]$

For this sequence, I'm having trouble finding out if it converges or diverges.

Can anyone help me to find a way on to do it?

Answer (score 1):

Use L’Hôpital’s Rule to determine that $x/(x^2+1)$ tends to 0 as $x \to \infty$, for $x \in \mathbb{R}$. The result is, of course, still true when $x \in \mathbb{N}$. Finally, use the fact that $|a_n| \to 0$ implies $a_n \to 0$.

Answer (score 1):

$$0\leq\left|\frac{\left(-1\right)^{n-1}n}{n^{2}+1}\right|\leq\frac{n}{n^{2}+1}\leq\frac{1}{n}$$ so the sequence converges to $0$ by the squeeze theorem.

Answer (score 1):

The given sequence is LT the sequence 1/n for every n in N and so share epsilon neighborhoods about zero, no matter how small epsilon is and so converges to zero along with 1/n.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps start by inputing values of $n$? See how the sequence behaves.

Comment: I did that, I noticed that the signs are alternating and I also noticed that the denominator for each value is getting bigger faster than the numerator, which is converging, but what does it mean for alternating numbers though?

Comment: @user354632 Do the terms of the sequence approach a fixed value?

Comment: @T.M. Yes it does

Comment: @user354632 Does that tell you anything about convergence or divergence?

Comment: @i707107 The question only asks about sequences not series. Though the user may be confused on that too.

Comment: @T.M. Well, the denominator for the alternating not numbers of the sequence are getting bigger faster than the numerator, so it is converging, right?

Comment: @user354632 Don't worry so much about the denominator, just the overall value of each term. What is the definition of convergence for a sequence?

Comment: @T.M. Thanks for pointing that out. It was my mistake assuming that the question was about the convergence/divergence of series. For the sequence, we can just do $|a_n|=\frac n{n^2+1} = \frac{ \frac1n }{1+ \frac1{n^2}} \rightarrow \frac 0{1+0} = 0.$ I will delete my comment about series convergence/divergence.

Comment: @i707107 We can do lots of things. :) Just trying to help the OP understand.